# I have a table with column AGE with numbers. I wanted to cluster similar number and count

Tags: excel, pandas

| AGE | CARD | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 20000 |
| 10 | 1 | 3000 |
| 25 | 0 | 2000 |
| 10 | 1 | 20000 |
| 18 | 1 | 3000 |
| 10 | 0 | 2000 |
| 12 | 1 | 20000 |
| 10 | 1 | 3000 |
| 10 | 0 | 2000 |

I want to count Age 10 as 4.

The first two rows (group) should be counted as 1 and 10 appearing in different rows can be added individually and the last two rows (group of age 10) should be counted as 1.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that data is in a table named "Table1":

`=COUNT(1/FREQUENCY(IF(Table1[AGE]=10,ROW(Table1[AGE])),IF(Table1[AGE]<>10,ROW(Table1[AGE]))))`

Comment: the count is coming 0 which is not true.

Comment: Perhaps your version of Excel requires committing that formula with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, though I have a feeling that that construction should not require  it even in older versions of Excel. In any case, I have tested on the data you provided and it returns 4, as desired.

Comment: thank you so much. It has solved the problem.